# append a single sensor value to panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe like that

```
general_pd =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['TimeStamp','C_strain_COY', 'C_strain_CUY', 'C_strain_ROX','C_strain_CUX', 'C_strain_CMX',                        'C_strain_COX', 'C_strain_LOX', 'C_temp_CUY', 'C_temp_COY', 'C_temp_CUX', 'C_temp_CMX', 'C_temp_COX'])
```

I have several lits, basically 14 sensors S1 - to s14.
I'm trying to append a single value to each column from S but I get empty data.

```
def process_sensor_list(dataframe, sensor, name):

    for i in range(len(sensor)):
            dataframe.loc[i] = (sensor[i])



    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S1, 'C_strain_COY')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S2, 'C_strain_CUY')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S3, 'C_strain_ROX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S4, 'C_strain_CUX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S5, 'C_strain_CMX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S6, 'C_strain_COX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, S7, 'C_strain_LOX')

    process_sensor_list(general_pd, T1, 'C_temp_CUY')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, T2, 'C_temp_COY')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, T3, 'C_temp_CUX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, T4, 'C_temp_CMX')
    process_sensor_list(general_pd, T5, 'C_temp_COX')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe = dataframe.append({'TimeStamp' : 1 ,'C_strain_COY' : 2, 'C_strain_CUY' : 3, ... }, ignore_index=True)
```

If you want to append to existing column, just append the dictionary of single values with the keys.

Comment: what is S- ? you mean C ?

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue, it justs add columns with sensor values. What I want is to append sensor values to each column

Comment: Please give it a check now.

Comment: it doesnt append row by row from a list. I have a problem that time stamps are larger in number than sensor values.. for example timestamps are 180 values, while sensor values are 80 for example.